# Assistance with opening additional ports - CentOS

Tags: centos, ssh, port

I'm trying to open an additional outgoing port on my VPS (port 5900).

Here is my /etc/sysconfig/iptables:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5 on Sun Jul 10 11:27:12 2011
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [68:4952]
:INPUT ACCEPT [68:4952]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [60:7060]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [60:7060]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jul 10 11:27:12 2011
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5 on Sun Jul 10 11:27:12 2011
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [68:4952]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [60:7060]
:RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 5900 -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jul 10 11:27:12 2011
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5 on Sun Jul 10 11:27:12 2011
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [18:1080]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jul 10 11:27:12 2011
```

However, the port 5900 is still closed.

Can someone assist me with this? Thanks.

Comment: 1) The rule you have for 5900 is an input rule, not output.  
2) Normally output is not blocket by firewall, only input.  
  
Why do you think the outgoing port 5900 is blocked?  Is it not likely that it is either a external firewall issue, or that is is the 5900 incomming on the receing port which is blocked?  How did you test it?

Comment: Also, if the VPS is accessed over a VPN, then most VPN implementations runs over UDP and not TCP

Answer (score 0):

The policy on your output chain is accept. There are no rules denying output on port 5900 in your configuration.

Are you sure that you have something listening on port 5900 ?

try

```
sudo lsof -l :5900
```

or

```
sudo netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep 5900
```

to see what (if anything) is attached.

Comment: It's not used by anything.

Comment: If there is nothing there then you have to fix that before 'fixing' your firewall.

Comment: How do I go by 'fixing' that? Sorry, I'm new to this VPS firewall stuff.

Comment: I have no idea, as you haven't said what your running that needs to use port 5900. If you turn your firewall off `/sbin/service iptables stop` can you do what you want ?

Comment: Apologies for the lack of information. I need the port 5900 so I can run a gaming server.

Comment: Is the gaming server running ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you mean "incoming", not "outgoing" port 5900, because your outgoing port is properly opened by your current rules.

Usually I get rid of the RH-Firewall-1-INPUT chain and use the following:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

# Allow traffic from the loopback interface
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow ICMP traffic as it helps with connection diagnostics
-A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT

# Allow traffic from already existing connections
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow connections on port 5900
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5900 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

COMMIT
```

But if you want to keep as close to the original CentOS configuration as possible, you could try the following:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]

-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A FORWARD -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT

-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 255 -j ACCEPT

-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5900 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

COMMIT
```

The problem with your current ruleset is that you don't send all incoming traffic to the RH-Firewall-1-INPUT chain, which is done with the following line:

```
-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
```

Also, don't forget to reload your rules with **service iptables restart**.

Comment: I tried both rules, however, it still says it's closed.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly are you trying to do? This way it will be much easier for us to help you. I am asking because your answers make me think that your problem isn't with the firewall, but with something else.

Comment: I'm not quite sure myself. I just need the port 5900 open so I can run a gaming server.

Comment: Run the following command to check if your gaming server is running and listening on the right port: **netstat -punta 2>/dev/null | grep LISTEN | grep :5900**

Comment: Ok, it's more of a "login server" file that runs off that port. To start the login server, I run "screen php login-server.php".

Comment: My question is still valid - does the command I wrote above return something?

Comment: No, your command does not return anything.

Comment: Ok, that means the there's nothing listening on port 5900 - you should make sure the the script is running and that it is really binding to port 5900. Maybe you should start another thread, because we are out of the scope of the original question, and your firewall should be fine by now.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for VNC and your VPS is hosted on Amazon, then make sure to open the security restrictions in your amazon security group as well (by default amazon only allow port 22 and 80).

Output port are normally not blocked -- so probably nothing to do on the host originating the connection.

Also, the firewall rule for 5900 should be on the **receiving** host (i.e. your VPS), And I would have guessed it would have to look something like this;

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m state --dport 5800 --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

BUT with the addition of checking that the IP is from you network and not from the internet in general (opening VNC to the public is probably not secure).

Finally, if your organization also have a firewall, you may want to check if the firewall prevent outgoing connection on unauthorized ports.